# Determine the equations of the circles

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> EXERCISE: Determine the equations of the circles that pass through the points $(2, 3)$ and $(3, 6)$, and are tangent to the line $2x + y − 2 = 0.$

My idea was, first, to notice that the points $(2,3)$ and $(3,6)$ belong to the circle, then substitute in the general equation the equation of a circle.
Thus I arrived at the equation of the possible centers of the circumference.
Then, it remained to look for the circles with a center satisfying the equation that I found, and that were tangent to the line $2x+y-2=0,$ so I calculated the distance between a possible center and the tangent and said that this was equal to the radius.
But then I didn't know what to do. I hope someone can help me to solve it

Comment: What's the center

Comment: the exercise does not give it but i determined the equation of the possible centers by substituting the two points belonging to the circumference in the general formula of the circumference. The equation of possible centers is 2x0+6yo-32=0 with (xo,yo) being the center.

Answer (score 6):

I don't undertand how the accepted answer arrives at the solution (well at least one of them), so I will explain how I did it.
We are given two points (2,3) and (3,6), we also know a point of the line $\large y = -2x + 2$ is part of the circle, let's call it (x,y) and let's call the center of the circle (h,k), using the equation of a circle we get the following system of equations:
$$\large \begin{cases}(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2\\(2-h)^2+(3-k)^2=r^2\\(3-h)^2+(6-k)^2=r^2\end{cases}$$
Now we need to turn this system of equations into one in 3 variables, to do this we'll express x and y in terms of h and k using relationships between these variables.

We know that (x,y) lie on a line which is perpendicular to $\large y=-2x+2$ and passes through (h,k), so:
$$\large y= \frac{1}{2}(x-h)+k$$
Using the equation of the tangent line we express y in terms of x and substitute into the perpendicular line equation:
$$\large -2x+2=\frac{1}{2}(x-h)+k$$
And now we solve for x:
$$\large x=\frac{h-2k+4}{5}$$
So, in resume, we can express y in terms of x, and x in terms of h and k, and the system of equations becomes:
$$\large \begin{cases}
(\frac{h-2k+4}{5}-h)^2+(-2\frac{h-2k+4}{5}+2-k)^2=r^2\\
(2-h)^2+(3-k)^2=r^2\\
(3-h)^2+(6-k)^2=r^2
\end{cases}$$
Plugging this system into an equation solver (because you don't want to lose your sanity) gives:
$$\large(h,k,r)=(1,5,\sqrt{5})$$
$$\large(h,k,r)=(13,1,5\sqrt{5})$$
So the circles' equations are:
$$\large (x-1)^2+(y-5)^2=5$$
$$\large (x-13)^2+(y-1)^2=125$$
diagram by courtesy of [PM 2Ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/207316/pm-2ring)
[image: diagram]

Comment: You have a total of 5 unknowns and 5 equations, the first set of three and then the two line equations right afterwards. That gives (assuming independence) a finite number of solutions. This gives the proper general solution (which the currently accepted answer is not) but I wonder whether there is better way to solve this that doesn't require so much 'brute force'.

Comment: Here's a diagram https://i.stack.imgur.com/atrpm.png plotted using https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjU0KwjAQhfeCdwhZTWoqNCXd5Q7uxYWkoQZiRicBPb7TQkGlqxne937ICifKkypYtd_5TgtvWAF-rNJ8ey06JicWHwkrmNY0bwat0WJQCzkwwphrgTMY3c-xXg_qskIfyacAczlZHsCE5CSFUf7EF8MGXOM8aJuvAqRrnsJ_h9nix3LDF0wUxxRzKE7eY0aS6gP0ZEPo&lang=sage

Comment: @quarague The numbers are "nice", so the system of 3 equations for $(h,k,r^2)$ isn't that hard to solve by hand.

Comment: @PM2Ring True, I did that as well, but it seems this problem should also be solvable with straight-edge and compass so I was hoping there is some clever geometric insight that lets one avoid setting up a system of 5 equations with 5 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

The radius will be $$r=d(l, C) =\frac{|2c_1+c_2-2|}{\sqrt{5}}, $$ where $C=(c_1, c_2)$ is the center. Since the center verifices that $2c_1+6c_2-32=0$, it implies that $c_1=16-3c_2$, so $$r=\frac{|32-6c_2+c_2-2|}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{|30-5c_2|}{\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5}|6-c_2|.$$ Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Yes, i mean, i understand that, i also did that but then i dont know how to continue.

Comment: You have to compute explicitely the centers

Comment: Because i know that and i also know that the possible center belong to the line 2c1+6c2-32=0 but i dont know how to continue

Comment: Edited it. Check it

Answer (score 1):

Label the given points $A(2,3), B(3,6)$ and the line $p: 2x+y-2=0.$
The center of every convenient circle lies on the bisector $b$ of the segment $AB,$ its equation is
$$b: x+3y-16=0$$ and parametric equations
\begin{equation}
{b:\bigg\{\begin{matrix}x = & 3t  -16 \\
y = & t  
\end{matrix}}
 \qquad t\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
We are searching for all $\;t\in\mathbb{R}\;$ such that the point $S_t$ is equidistant to $A,B$ and $p.$ It is clear that $|AS_t|=|BS_t|.$  After plugging into
$$dist(S_t,p)=|BS_t|$$ and some simple algebra, we obtain
$$\sqrt5 \cdot|6-t|=\sqrt{(13-3t)^2+(t-6)^2}$$
Squaring and simplifying leads to a quadratic equation
$$t^2-6t+5=0.$$
The rest is straightforward.